# Подскажите пожалуйста. Как после ответа начать программу сначала и сократить код или обойтись без приведения ответа к нижнему регистру?

Tags: python

Начал изучать 2 дня назад. Простите за возможно глупые вопросы.

```
str = str.lower(input('Enter word: '))

flag = 0

for char in str:
    if (str.count(char)>1):
        flag = 1
        break
if flag == 0:
    print(' It is an isogram')

else:
    print(' It\'s not an isogram')
```

Comment: как начать программу с начала написано примерно в 12345 вопросах на этом сайте. Умение и особенно желание искать информацию - важнейший навык программиста.

Comment: Спасибо. разобраслся наконец. Ввод данных прописывал не внутри функции while, у меня результат выдавался бесконечно, а не возвращался к началу программы. Статей и ответов действительно много, но ошибку без опыта найти у себя трудно)

Answer (score 1):

ваши ошибки:

1. не используйте в качестве названия переменных имена функций и вообще ключевые слова питона (`str = str.lower(input('Enter word: '))`)
2. можно использовать функции без обращения к методам `str`

   `lower()` вместо `str.lower()`

изограмму можно получить проще

```
text = lower(input('Enter word: '))

if len(set(text)) != len(text):
    print(' It is an isogram')

else:
    print(' It\'s not an isogram')
```

**вариант 1:**

```
flag = len(set(text)) != len(text)
```

**вариант 2:**

```
flag = any(text.count(l) > 1 for l in text)
```

**вариант 3:**

```
flag = sum(text.count(l) for l in text) != len(text)
```

**вариант 4:**

```
import math
flag = math.prod(text.count(l) for l in text) != 1
```

Comment: Благодарю. Буду разбираться...